# Spring Boot Unit Testing with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-security, spring-test, mockmvc

I have a simple application that I have setup with spring security using a custom MySql Database. Now I'm writing test cases for it and they seems to fail on login page and anything that works after the login. My question is how do I write test cases for it to check the successful login and the subsequent requests?

My Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Autowired 
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    /** Providing the queries and data source for security*/
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception 
    {
        auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    /** Defining fine grained access for ADMIN and CUSTOMER user */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
            authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority(AppRole.CUSTOMER.toString())
                .antMatchers("/health/**").hasAuthority(AppRole.ADMIN.toString())
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(AppRole.ADMIN.toString()).anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .successHandler(successHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    /** Defining ant matchers that should ignore the paths and provide no access to any one */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception 
    {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

My Custom Success Handler:

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler 
{
    /** Getting reference to UserService */
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) 
                    throws IOException, ServletException, RuntimeException 
    {
        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
        User authUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        com.crossover.techtrial.java.se.model.User user = userService.findUserByUsername(authUser.getUsername());
        session.setAttribute("userId", user.getUserId());
        session.setAttribute("username", authUser.getUsername());
        session.setAttribute("accountId", user.getAccountId());
        //set our response to OK status
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        authorities.forEach(authority -> 
                                { 
                                    if(authority.getAuthority().equals(AppRole.ADMIN.toString())) 
                                    { 
                                        session.setAttribute("role", AppRole.ADMIN);
                                        try
                                        {
                                            //since we have created our custom success handler, its up to us to where
                                            //we will redirect the user after successfully login
                                            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/admin/home");
                                        } 
                                        catch (IOException e) 
                                        {
                                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                        }                                                                           
                                    }
                                    else if (authority.getAuthority().equals(AppRole.CUSTOMER.toString()))
                                    {
                                        session.setAttribute("role", AppRole.CUSTOMER);
                                        try
                                        {
                                            //since we have created our custom success handler, its up to us to where
                                            //we will redirect the user after successfully login
                                            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/user/home");
                                        } 
                                        catch (IOException e) 
                                        {
                                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                        }   
                                    }
                                });

    }

}
```

After some seraching I tried to write test cases like this but they don't seem to be working:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class TrialApplicationTests 
    {
        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

        @Autowired
        private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

        @Autowired
        private MockHttpServletRequest request;

        private MockMvc mockMvc;


        @Test
        public void contextLoads() 
        {
        }

        @Before
        public void setup() 
        {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                    .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
                    .build();
        }
        @Test
        public void verifiesLoginPageLoads() throws Exception 
        {
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/"))
                   .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().hasNoErrors())
                   .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("login"))
                   .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
        }

        @Test
        public void testUserLogin()  throws Exception
        {
            HttpSession session = mockMvc.perform(post("/login")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) 
                    .param("username", "test")
                    .param("password", "test123")
                    )
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                    //.andExpect(redirectedUrl("/user/home"))
                    .andReturn()
                    .getRequest()
                    .getSession();

            request.setSession(session);

            SecurityContext securityContext = (SecurityContext)   session.getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);

            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
        }

        @Test
        public void testRetrieveUserBookings() throws Exception
        {
            testUserLogin();

            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("user/bookings"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().hasNoErrors())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("bookings"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("user/bookings"))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Booking")));
        }

    }

I searched on the net and there are links WithMockUser and UserDetails, but the problem is as you can see I'm setting a my primary key userId in the session in my custom success handler. So I would also need to get the session in my test. Please tell me the simplest way to write tests that will work, possibly with code since I'm new with security and all such. 

UPDATE:

I changed the code as suggested but still getting the 404 error on my testRetrieveUserBookings. Any more ideas?

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public class TrialApplicationTests 
{
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    MockMvc mockMvc; 

    @Autowired
    ForestApiClient apiClient;

    @Autowired
    AccountClient accountClient;

    @Autowired
    AirlineClient airlineClient;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    private final String INTEGRATION_ACCOUNT = "account1";

    private MockHttpSession mockSession;

    private Authentication authentication;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() 
    {
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() 
    {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                //.addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain)
                .build();   

        mockSession = new MockHttpSession(webApplicationContext.getServletContext(), UUID.randomUUID().toString()); 
        mockSession.setAttribute("userId", 3);
        mockSession.setAttribute("accountId", "ZWR26539");
    }

    @Test
    public void testVerifiesLoginPageLoads() throws Exception 
    {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/"))
               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().hasNoErrors())
               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("login"))
               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRegistration()  throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/registration")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) 
                .param("username", "test2")
                .param("password", "test123")
                .param("email", "crossovertestuser@gmail.com")
                .param("address", "Some Address")
                .param("accountCurrency", "USD")
                )
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().hasNoErrors())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("user"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("registration"))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("User has been registered successfully")));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="test",roles={"USER","ADMIN"})
    public void testRetrieveUserBookings() throws Exception
    {

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("user/bookings"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().hasNoErrors())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("bookings"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("user/bookings"))
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Booking")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only getting session inside the test, then you can go for MockHttpSession.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mock = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();        
    MockHttpSession httpSession = new MockHttpSession(webAppContext.getServletContext(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}

@Test
public void test1(){
    mock.perform(get("/").session(mockSession)).perfor();
}
```

Comment: I did what you told me however it seems it's not picking values from the session. I'm getting 404 error. Please see the edit for updated code.